# Splitting a single column into multiple observation using R

Tags: r, data.table, medical, data-cleaning, splitstackshape

I am working on HCUP data and this has range of values in one single column that needs to be split into multiple columns. Below is the HCUP data frame for reference :

```
code            label
61000-61003     excision of CNS
0169T-0169T     ventricular shunt
```

The desired output should be :

```
code            label
61000           excision of CNS
61001           excision of CNS
61002           excision of CNS
61003           excision of CNS
0169T           ventricular shunt
```

My approach to this problem is using the package *splitstackshape* and using this code

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(hcup, "code", "-")[, list(code = code_1:code_2, by = label)]
```

This approach leads to memory issues. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Some comments :

- The data has many letters apart from "T".
- The letter can be either in the front or at the very end but not in between two numbers.
- There is no change of letter from "T" to "U" in one single range

Comment: Hmmm I'm not very experienced with data.table, but I can't see how your apprach could work - `Code_1` (shouldn't it be `code_1`?) and `code_2` must be numeric, if you want to build a sequence, e.g. `hcup <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors = F, text="code label\n61000-61003 excision_of_CNS\n0169T-0169T ventricular_shunt"); cSplit(hcup, "code", "-")[, list(Code = seq(as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", code_1)), as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", code_2)))), by = label]`.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted the edits. I am not particular about "splitstackshape" as such. Is there a possibility to write a function which can handle this problem?

Comment: This might be of help from the `splitstackshape` documentation:  If you know that all values in the column would have the same number of values per row after being split, you should use the `cSplit_f` function instead, which uses `fread` instead of `strsplit` and is generally faster.

Comment: So maybe you can give us a little more info.  It the letter `T` always the letter?  Is it always at the end of the string?

Comment: First - The data has many letters apart from "T". Second - The letter can be either in the front or at the very end but not in between two numbers. Third - There is no change of letter from "T" to "U" in one single range.

Comment: One can access the original data here - [link](http://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/ccs_svcsproc/ccssvcproc.jsp)

Comment: To second-guess the question, I think expanding the data frame might not be the thing that you want to do in the end.  Splitting the code column into `begin` and `end`, and storing the `code.prefix` and `code.suffix` seems like it would make matching a lot simpler, which is presumably the use case that this is aimed at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `all.is.numeric` from `Hmisc`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% separate(code, into=c("code1", "code2")) %>%
        rowwise %>%
        mutate(lists = ifelse(all.is.numeric(c(code1, code2)),
                         list(as.character(seq(from = as.numeric(code1), to = as.numeric(code2)))),
                         list(code1))) %>%
        unnest(lists) %>%
        select(code = lists, label)

Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

   code             label
  (chr)            (fctr)
1 61000   excision of CNS
2 61001   excision of CNS
3 61002   excision of CNS
4 61003   excision of CNS
5 0169T ventricular shunt
```

An edit to fix ranges with character values. Brings down the simplicity a little:

```
dff %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
        separate(code, into=c("code1", "code2")) %>%
        group_by(row) %>%
        summarise(lists = if(all.is.numeric(c(code1, code2)))
                              {list(str_pad(as.character(
                                   seq(from = as.numeric(code1), to = as.numeric(code2))),
                                         nchar(code1), pad="0"))}
                          else if(grepl("^[0-9]", code1))
                              {list(str_pad(paste0(as.character(
                                   seq(from = extract_numeric(code1), to = extract_numeric(code2))),
                                      strsplit(code1, "[0-9]+")[[1]][2]),
                                         nchar(code1), pad = "0"))}
                          else
                              {list(paste0(
                                      strsplit(code1, "[0-9]+")[[1]],
                                      str_pad(as.character(
                                    seq(from = extract_numeric(code1), to = extract_numeric(code2))),
                                         nchar(gsub("[^0-9]", "", code1)), pad="0")))},
                   label = first(label)) %>%
        unnest(lists) %>%
        select(-row)
Source: local data frame [15 x 2]

               label lists
               (chr) (chr)
1    excision of CNS 61000
2    excision of CNS 61001
3    excision of CNS 61002
4  ventricular shunt 0169T
5  ventricular shunt 0170T
6  ventricular shunt 0171T
7    excision of CNS 01000
8    excision of CNS 01001
9    excision of CNS 01002
10    some procedure A2543
11    some procedure A2544
12    some procedure A2545
13    some procedure A0543
14    some procedure A0544
15    some procedure A0545
```

data:

```
dff <- structure(list(code = c("61000-61002", "0169T-0171T", "01000-01002", 
"A2543-A2545", "A0543-A0545"), label = c("excision of CNS", "ventricular shunt", 
"excision of CNS", "some procedure", "some procedure")), .Names = c("code", 
"label"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This looks good. But it omits codes like "0169T" in the final output.

Comment: This solution is very close but still misses those code where the letter comes first. For example, code "A4245" does not get added to the final database.

Answer (score 6):

**Original Answer:** See below for update.

First, I made your example data a little more challenging by adding the first row to the bottom.

```
dff <- structure(list(code = c("61000-61003", "0169T-0169T", "61000-61003"
), label = c("excision of CNS", "ventricular shunt", "excision of CNS"
)), .Names = c("code", "label"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

dff
#          code             label
# 1 61000-61003   excision of CNS
# 2 0169T-0169T ventricular shunt
# 3 61000-61003   excision of CNS
```

We can use the sequence operator `:` to get the sequences for the `code` column, wrapping with `tryCatch()` so we can avoid an error on, and save the values that cannot be sequenced. First we split the values by the dash mark `-` then run it through `lapply()`.

```
xx <- lapply(
    strsplit(dff$code, "-", fixed = TRUE), 
    function(x) tryCatch(x[1]:x[2], warning = function(w) x)
)
data.frame(code = unlist(xx), label = rep(dff$label, lengths(xx)))
#     code             label
# 1  61000   excision of CNS
# 2  61001   excision of CNS
# 3  61002   excision of CNS
# 4  61003   excision of CNS
# 5  0169T ventricular shunt
# 6  0169T ventricular shunt
# 7  61000   excision of CNS
# 8  61001   excision of CNS
# 9  61002   excision of CNS
# 10 61003   excision of CNS
```

We're trying to apply the sequence operator `:` to each element from `strsplit()`, and if taking `x[1]:x[2]` is not possible then this returns just the values for those elements and proceeds with the sequence `x[1]:x[2]` otherwise. Then we just replicate the values of the `label` column based on the resulting lengths in `xx` to get the new `label` column.

---

**Update:** Here is what I've come up with in response to your edit.  Replace `xx` above with

```
xx <- lapply(strsplit(dff$code, "-", TRUE), function(x) {
    s <- stringi::stri_locate_first_regex(x, "[A-Z]")
    nc <- nchar(x)[1L]
    fmt <- function(n) paste0("%0", n, "d")
    if(!all(is.na(s))) {
        ss <- s[1,1]
        fmt <- fmt(nc-1)
        if(ss == 1L) {
            xx <- substr(x, 2, nc)
            paste0(substr(x, 1, 1), sprintf(fmt, xx[1]:xx[2]))
        } else {
            xx <- substr(x, 1, ss-1)
            paste0(sprintf(fmt, xx[1]:xx[2]), substr(x, nc, nc))
        }
    } else {
        sprintf(fmt(nc), x[1]:x[2])
    }
})
```

Yep, it's complicated.  Now if we take the following data frame `df2` as a test case

```
df2 <- structure(list(code = c("61000-61003", "0169T-0174T", "61000-61003", 
"T0169-T0174"), label = c("excision of CNS", "ventricular shunt", 
"excision of CNS", "ventricular shunt")), .Names = c("code", 
"label"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

and run the `xx` code from above on it, we can get the following result.

```
data.frame(code = unlist(xx), label = rep(df2$label, lengths(xx)))
#     code             label
# 1  61000   excision of CNS
# 2  61001   excision of CNS
# 3  61002   excision of CNS
# 4  61003   excision of CNS
# 5  0169T ventricular shunt
# 6  0170T ventricular shunt
# 7  0171T ventricular shunt
# 8  0172T ventricular shunt
# 9  0173T ventricular shunt
# 10 0174T ventricular shunt
# 11 61000   excision of CNS
# 12 61001   excision of CNS
# 13 61002   excision of CNS
# 14 61003   excision of CNS
# 15 T0169 ventricular shunt
# 16 T0170 ventricular shunt
# 17 T0171 ventricular shunt
# 18 T0172 ventricular shunt
# 19 T0173 ventricular shunt
# 20 T0174 ventricular shunt
```

Comment: This works great. But the input data has codes like "'0005T-0006T". In this case only 0005T gets labeled in the final output but code 0006T is missing.

Comment: My apologies, the data-set was big and I missed it. Yes, i would like to have both the codes in the final output.

Comment: Not sure if your example is possible. I'm guessing each label only shows up once in the raw data.

Answer (score 3):

Create a sequencing rule for such codes:

```
seq_code <- function(from,to){

    ext = function(x, part) gsub("([^0-9]?)([0-9]*)([^0-9]?)", paste0("\\",part), x)

    pre = unique(sapply(list(from,to), ext, part = 1 ))
    suf = unique(sapply(list(from,to), ext, part = 3 ))

    if (length(pre) > 1 | length(suf) > 1){
        return("NO!")
    }

    num = do.call(seq, lapply(list(from,to), function(x) as.integer(ext(x, part = 2))))
    len = nchar(from)-nchar(pre)-nchar(suf)

    paste0(pre, sprintf(paste0("%0",len,"d"), num), suf)

}
```

With @jeremycg's example:

```
setDT(dff)[,.(
  label = label[1], 
  code  = do.call(seq_code, tstrsplit(code,'-'))
), by=.(row=seq(nrow(dff)))]
```

which gives

```
    row             label  code
 1:   1   excision of CNS 61000
 2:   1   excision of CNS 61001
 3:   1   excision of CNS 61002
 4:   2 ventricular shunt 0169T
 5:   2 ventricular shunt 0170T
 6:   2 ventricular shunt 0171T
 7:   3   excision of CNS 01000
 8:   3   excision of CNS 01001
 9:   3   excision of CNS 01002
10:   4    some procedure A2543
11:   4    some procedure A2544
12:   4    some procedure A2545
13:   5    some procedure A0543
14:   5    some procedure A0544
15:   5    some procedure A0545
```

---

Data copied from @jeremycg's answer:

```
dff <- structure(list(code = c("61000-61002", "0169T-0171T", "01000-01002", 
"A2543-A2545", "A0543-A0545"), label = c("excision of CNS", "ventricular shunt", 
"excision of CNS", "some procedure", "some procedure")), .Names = c("code", 
"label"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're patient enough, you'd probably parse the strings into separate pieces instead of the eval/parse trick, alas I'm not, so:

```
fancy.seq = function(x) eval(parse(text=sub(', \\)', ')', sub('\\(, ', '(',
               sub('.*?([0-9]+)(.*)-(.*?)([1-9][0-9]*).*',
                   'paste0("\\3",
                           formatC(\\1:\\4, width=log10(\\4)+1, format="d", flag="0"),
                           "\\2")',
                   x)))))
# using example from jeremycg's answer
dt[, .(fancy.seq(code), label), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
#    nrow    V1             label
# 1:    1 61000   excision of CNS
# 2:    1 61001   excision of CNS
# 3:    1 61002   excision of CNS
# 4:    2 0169T ventricular shunt
# 5:    2 0170T ventricular shunt
# 6:    2 0171T ventricular shunt
# 7:    3 01000   excision of CNS
# 8:    3 01001   excision of CNS
# 9:    3 01002   excision of CNS
#10:    4 A2543    some procedure
#11:    4 A2544    some procedure
#12:    4 A2545    some procedure
#13:    5 A0543    some procedure
#14:    5 A0544    some procedure
#15:    5 A0545    some procedure
```

If unclear what the above is doing - just run the `sub` commands one by one on one of the "code" strings.

Comment: `\\2:\\4` is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

A less elegant way to do it:

```
# the data
hcup <- data.frame(code=c("61000-61003", "0169T-0169T"),
                   label=c("excision of CNS", "ventricular shunt"), stringsAsFactors = F)
hcup
>         code             label
>1 61000-61003   excision of CNS
>2 0169T-0169T ventricular shunt

# reshaping
# split the code ranges into separate columns
seq.ends <- cbind(do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(hcup$code, "-")), hcup$label)
# create a list with a data.frame for each original line
new.list <- apply(seq.ends, 1, FUN=function(x){data.frame(code=if(grepl("\\d{5}", x[1])){
                     z<-x[1]:x[2]}else{z<-x[1]}, label=rep(x[3], length(z)),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)})
# collapse the list into a df
new.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(new.list, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=F))

new.df
>     code             label
>1.1 61000   excision of CNS
>1.2 61001   excision of CNS
>1.3 61002   excision of CNS
>1.4 61003   excision of CNS
>2   0169T ventricular shunt
```